# add picker in tableViewRow error

Tags: android, titanium, tableview, picker

I'm working on a selector on a tableViewRow, works perfect, but when choosing a pickerRow also this is repeated in row 4. Any idea why this happens?

This is latest version Android Titanium Studio

```
var tipo = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    width:'15%',
    right:30,
    top:0
});

caja.add(tipo);

/*
var columTipo = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn({

});

tipo.add(columTipo);
*/
//var rowPromo = [];
var data = [];
var db = Ti.Database.open("elite.db","elite");
var selectPromo = db.execute('select * from PROMOTION_TYPES');
var i = 0;
while(selectPromo.isValidRow()) {
    i++;
    var rowPromo = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({title:selectPromo.fieldByName('name')});
    //tipo[obj.numero].add(rowPromo[i]);
    data.push(rowPromo);
    selectPromo.next();
}

tipo.add(data);
tipo.selectionIndicator = true;

tipo.addEventListener('change',function(e) {
    //e.setBackgroundColor('#ccc');
    alert('Promo'+e.selectedValue);
})
```

Comment: "but when choosing a pickerRow also this is repeated in row 4" - what does it mean? Can you clarify your question? Either explain your issue or add screenshot regarding your issue. So that we can help you easily.

Comment: Right, selecting a first picker pickerRow: Suppose I select the pickerRow 4 (item 4), when I move to row 4 of the table, and select the row that picker I see selected'm also pickerRow 4 (the item 4)